Fastfetch colors not loading everytime
I have fastfetch installed and want a smaller configuration to be started, every time i open a terminal. This in itself works perfectly. However most of the times the colors don't load at all but i get the information as well as the small logo of my distro. The command to start fastfetch is inside my .zshrc and the command used is the following:
fastfetch -c /home/nico/.config/fastfetch/os.jsonc

Is there anything i am missing like an additional flag to always load the colors?

What's the output of typeset -p TERM; echoti colors? And what's your terminal emulator application and version thereof?

I add the same issue with ZSH, Powerlevel10k & Oh-my-ZSH.
According to this discussion, it's related to p10k loading at the beginning of the .zshrc
Putting neofetch loading before the p10k instant prompt code made the thing in my config
